# Proving that $f=\{(x^n,x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a function for positive odd integers $n$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Question:**
Prove or disprove that, for any positive odd integer n, $f=\{(x^n,x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a function.

I believe the set defines a function.

**My attempt:**
Let $n$ be a positive odd integer.

Claim: $f$ defines a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

1. Note that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then, $x^n \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $f \subset \mathbb{R^2}$.
2. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $(y,y^{1/n}) \in f$. Thus, we have shown the existence of an element $x$, such that $(y,x) \in f$.
3. Suppose that for some $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $(y,y_1^{1/n}),(y,y_2^{1/n}) \in f$. Thus, $y_1^{1/n}=y_2^{1/n}$. Thus $y_1=y_2.$

From 2 and 3, we conclude that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists ! x \in \mathbb{R}, (y,x) \in f$. Hence $f$ is a function. Since $n$ was arbitrary, $f$ is a function for any odd integer $n$.

Could someone tell me if it is correct? Please let me know if there are any points to improve on and if anything is incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: This is good, just a note: When developing theorems from first principles, this proposition would likely be involved in defining what $y^{1/n}$ means, so in that context a proof would want to avoid using that expression. But it would be similar, just proving that if $(x, y_1) \in f$ and $(x, y_2) \in f$ then $y_1^n=x=y_2^n$ and $y_1=y_2$ since $g(y)=y^n$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, aschepler. It was really helpful. About the last statement, I was a bit confused: if $(x,y_1) \in f$ and $(x,y_2) \in f$, then shouldn't it be $y_1 = x^n = y_2$? I think that the last statement in your comment shows that $\{(x,x^n)\}$ is an injective function. Could you tell me if I'm going wrong in my understanding? Thank you again

Comment: Perhaps the reuse of $x$ with different meaning is confusing. But if $(x,y_1) \in f$ then $(x,y_1) = (z^n, z)$ for some $z \in \mathbb{R}$, meaning $x=z^n$ and $y_1=z$. So $x=y_1^n$. The first-principles proof would need to prove, or rely on a previous proof, that $g(y)=y^n$ is injective to get from $y_1^n = y_2^n$ to $y_1 = y_2$. (And in fact, prove that $g$ is surjective to show the equivalent of your step 2.)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $n$ is odd, then $x^n=y^n$ implies $x=y$. Then the assignment $x^n\mapsto x$ is a function.

If $n$ is even, then $x^n=y^n$ implies $x=\pm y$. E.g., if $n=2$, then $4=2^2\mapsto 2$ and $4=(-2)^2\mapsto -2$ which does  not yield a function.

Comment: It's given that $n$ is odd, so no need to worry about evens.